# Need to loop through & modify cells in an Excel sheet... Where do I start?

Tags: vba, excel

**What I'm working with**

I need to modify a file (exported from salesforce) where rows have a unique ID, a name, and a column with the unique ID of another row from this table, identifying it as a "child" of that item.

1. ID  (*columnA*)
2. Name  (*columnB*)
3. ParentID  (*columnC*)

Image of unaffected data:

[image]

**What I need to accomplish**

My goal is to loop through the entire spreadsheet (55,000 rows) and change the ParentID to the value from the parent's Name column.

**My pseudo-code solution**

```
foreach row starting from the top {
    varA = [current row number for this loop];
    varX = [value in varA:columnC];
    if (varX == [regex value]) {
        foreach row starting from the top {
            varB = [current row number for this loop];
            if ([value in varB:columnA] == varX) {              
                foreach row starting from the top {
                    varC = [current row number for this loop];
                    if (varC:columnC = varB:columnA) {
                        [varC:columnC] = [varB:columnB];
                    }
                }
                break second foreach loop;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Image of data after manual fix:

[image]

**Research I've done so far**

I am working with excel, and I found resources discussing how to create a new macro, and some that even have examples, but I'm not confident that's going to be the right place for this. I also have a friend who is suggesting that it would be better to modify the file using Pandas, but that isn't something I'm familiar with either.

**My question:**

Where do I start? ...What is the proper tool to write a script to modify all of this?

Also, if possible, can you suggest a resource for me to use as reference when using the proper tool for this job?

Comment: So you have `001, Ted, 002` in the first and `002, Bob, 099` in the second and you want to change the first to be `001, Ted, Bob` ...? What if it cannot find a match?

Comment: Can you post a small picture of your expected result? and some sample data, you can forge it we don't need to see the actual values. If I understand you correctly this seems easily doable with a formula.

Comment: Considered just copying the names of the parents over to replace the ID? Or am I misunderstanding your needs? If copy/paste could solve it and there arent a lot of blank cells, just click the first in the name row, hold down CTRL+Shift and the click arrow-down. Copy it and paste it over the previous ID

Comment: Thanks for discussing this with me- I've added images as per Miguel's request.

Chris, by my estimate, manually doing a find+replace for every ParentID will take a few days to accomplish.

Answer (score 2):

Change this,

[image]

.. with this code,

```
Option Explicit

Sub wqweqrteq()
    Dim d As Long, dict As Object, vals As Variant

    Set dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")

    With Worksheets("salesforce")
        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            vals = .Value2
        End With

        For d = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            dict.Item(vals(d, 1)) = vals(d, 2)
        Next d

        For d = LBound(vals, 1) To UBound(vals, 1)
            If dict.exists(vals(d, 3)) Then
                vals(d, 3) = dict.Item(vals(d, 3))
            End If
        Next d

        With .Range(.Cells(2, "A"), .Cells(.Rows.Count, "C").End(xlUp))
            .Value = vals
        End With
    End With

End Sub
```

.. into this.

[image]

Comment: I opened the sheet, changed the name to 'salesforce' and the column names to match those here, then opened up "Visual Basic" from the developer tools, selected the 'salesforce' sheet, then in the white field to the right I entered your suggested code and clicked run.

It gives error code 429. Any idea why?

Comment: Well, since you decided it wasn't important to specify which line was actually throwing the error I'd hazard a guess that you couldn't create the scripting dictionary object. If that is the case, repair your Office installation.

Comment: As my initial request was for direction regarding what tool to use, I'm not ashamed to say that I'm still not sure I'm in the right place when pasting the code you gave above. Thus my verbose response asking for ideas as to why your solution didn't work.

The error that popped up didn't contain a line number, so I genuinely didn't decide anything about that.

Comment: Typically, you would be placing this in a standard module (Inert, Module or Alt+I, M) not a worksheet's code sheet but if you did place it on a worksheet's code sheet, it should run for that worksheet.

Answer (score 0):

The following **For loop** would fix your problem:

```
Sub UpdateID()

Dim lastrow As Long
Dim x As Long, y As Long, z As Long
Dim ParentName As String

lastrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For x = 2 To lastrow
    If Left(Cells(x, 3), 2) = 0 Then
        For y = 2 To lastrow
            If Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(y, 1).Value Then
            ParentName = Cells(y, 2).Value
            Exit For
            End If
        Next y
    End If

    For z = 2 To lastrow
        If Cells(z, 3).Value <> "" And Cells(x, 3).Value = Cells(z, 3).Value Then
        Cells(z, 3).Value = ParentName
        End If
    Next z
Next x

End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Pete, thanks for trying to help me here. I put this code into the Visual Basic Editor for the appropriate sheet, but after running the code Excel has been hanging for over ten minutes. Is that normal, or is there a chance I entered this in the wrong place?

Comment: @EddieKnight - It's normal for 50K rows of data. The way to speed it up is to use a dictionary and variant arrays.

Comment: Yeah, loops always take pretty long for large data sets.

Comment: Thanks for the help guys, but even on a reduced-size file this kept spinning for about 45 minutes... I think I have a fundamental misunderstanding of where to start with this stuff. I'm going to start looking for another solution. Thanks all the same!